# When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

When I `ssh` into a server, how can I pass an environment variable from the client to the server?  This environment variable changes between different invocations of ssh so I don't want to overwrite `$HOME/.ssh2/environment` every time I do an ssh call. How can I do this?

Comment: You question needs to be a liiittle more specific.

Comment: The question was clear enough to me. However, from the `ssh` man page, I don't see any way to do that other than setting the variable manually once you've logged in to the server, unless you modify ~/.ssh2/environment.

Comment: Is it a different variable each time? Or a different value?

Comment: Different value each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I pass an environment variable through an ssh command?](http://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command)

Comment: Other way round, as this is already more popular. It doesn't matter it's older.

Answer (score 162):

Of course, you can set the environment variable inside the command, however you'll have to be careful about quoting: remember that your shell is going to parse your local command line, and then the remote shell will have a go on the string it receives.

If you want a variable to get the same value on the server that it has on the client, try the `SendEnv` option:

```
ssh -o SendEnv=MYVAR server.example.com mycommand
```

This requires support from the server, though. With OpenSSH, the variable name has to be authorized in `/etc/sshd_config`.

If the server only allows certain specific variable names, you can work around that; for example a common setup allows `LC_*` through, and you can do the following:

```
ssh -o SendEnv=LC_MYVAR server.example.com 'MYVAR=$LC_MYVAR; unset LC_MYVAR; export MYVAR; mycommand'
```

If even `LC_*` is not an option, you can pass information in the `TERM` environment variable, which is always copied (there may be a length limit however). You'll still have to make sure that the remote shell doesn't restrict the `TERM` variable to designate a known terminal type. Pass the `-t` option to ssh if you're not starting a remote  interactive shell.

```
env TERM="extra information:$TERM" ssh -t server.example.com 'MYVAR=${TERM%:*}; TERM=${TERM##*:}; export MYVAR; mycommand'
```

Another possibility is to define the variable directly in the command:

```
ssh -t server.example.com 'export MYVAR="extra information"; mycommand'
```

Thus, if passing a local variable:

```
ssh -t server.example.com 'export MYVAR='"'$LOCALVAR'"'; mycommand'
```

However, beware of quoting issues: the value of the variable will be interpolated directly into the shell snippet executed on the remote side. The last example above assumes that `$LOCALVAR` does not contain any single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Thanks much, I was in a rage that the stupid LC_* variables are exported on ssh and your answer directed me where to look. I just have to disable that in ~/.ssh/config

Comment: I'm in the situation of the original poster, but the variable that I wanted forwarded is TERM, so I'm a bit puzzled by your answer. Has this automatic forwarding of TERM been disabled by recent OpenSSH versions?

Comment: @Doub The default is to refuse all environment variables on the server side, with `AcceptEnv` directives in `sshd_config` as desired by the administrator. But `TERM` is treated specially, as far as I know there is no way to filter it on the server side (it is set in the environment of the shell regardless of any configuration setting). Are you sure there isn't a profile script overriding it (like `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`)?

Comment: @Gilles: I tested it again, and unless I explicitly add TERM to my AcceptEnv directive, the TERM is not passed on. I not opening a shell, but running a command directly, for example: "ssh -o SendEnv=TERM shell.example.com env". That prints all environment variable, and TERM only appears if it's in SendEnv on the client and AcceptEnv on the server. If I run "ssh -o SendEnv=TERM shell.example.com echo \${TERM}" withoug the AcceptEnv or SendEnv, it prints "dumb", which I'm not sure where it comes from (env doesn't even list TERM in that case).

Comment: @Doub Oh, I see. `TERM` is only transmitted if the client requests the server to allocate a tty. If there's no terminal on the remote side, it would be useless to transmit `TERM`. When you specify a command, if you want to have a terminal on the remote side, you need the `-t` command line option (or `RequestTTY` in `~/.ssh/config`).

Comment: @Gilles: I see. My problem was that the Mercurial colour output was broken, and I assumed that it was because my xterm-256color TERM was not sent properly, but it's probably because of the lack of a tty.

Comment: @Doub The lack of a tty is what caused Mercurial not to use colors (like `ls`, `grep`, `git` and just about any other program with optional coloring). Either use `ssh -t` or `hg --config color.mode=ansi` (I think).

Comment: Security concern: be thoughtful when passing variables via command-line, *if* they contain sensitive info (like ID number, sensitive key, filename), as the value may be read by other users (via ps, for example).

Comment: @Crossfit_and_Beer You aren't addressing the asker.

Comment: `FOO=$(printf "%q" "$FOO")` is a good way to quote a string so it can be eval'd

Comment: You don't really need `-t`, you could also enclose the call in a new shell like so: `ssh server.example.com sh -c 'export MYVAR='"'$LOCALVAR'"'; mycommand'`

Comment: How to use `-o SendEnv` with multiple variables ? Thanks

Comment: @KaKi87 Either use a glob pattern or pass `-o SendEnv=…` multiple times.

Answer (score 31):

On your local client, in your `~/.ssh/config` you can add `SetEnv`, e.g.

```
Host myhost
  SetEnv FOO=bar
```

<sup>Note: Check `man ssh_config`.</sup>

Then on the server, make sure to allow client to pass certain environment variables in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` config file:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* FOO BAR*
```

<sup>Note: Check `man sshd_config`.</sup>

Comment: Worth noting, especially since OP asked about setting it to vary 'session to session', that, as with all `ssh_config` options, it can be set via flag too: `ssh -o 'SetEnv FOO=bar BAR=foo' [...]`. (If setting multiple vars, they must be supplied to a single `-o 'SetEnv`.)

Comment: I had a typical issue with allacritty so I used `SetEnv term=xterm` but also noticed on the Server that only `AcceptEnv Lang LC_*` was set. Why does it work?

Answer (score 21):

If you can administrate the target host you can configure sshd to allow passing your local environment variables along to the target host.

From the sshd_config man page:

```
 PermitUserEnvironment
     Specifies whether ~/.ssh/environment and environment= options in
     ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are processed by sshd.  The default is
     "no".  Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass
     access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such
     as LD_PRELOAD.
```

sshd configuration typically lives at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: It's very useful to know that this is set to "no" by default!

Answer (score 6):

So, on your client, you have some environment variable, and you want that to be available to the remote command? I don't think there's a way to have ssh magically pass it along, but you can probably do something like this. Instead of using, say:

```
ssh remote.host my_command
```

You can do this:

```
ssh remote.host env ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR my_command
```

Comment: "probably"? I wish I read that before actually trying this answer. Didn't work for me.

Comment: Care to elaborate on any errors received, etc?

Comment: @pioto Might be quoting, e.g. if ENV_VAR has spaces in it

Comment: On Mac you have to have -t option for an interactive version, otherwise it looks stuck. So this might work: $ ssh -t remote.host env ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR my_command

Answer (score 5):

@emptyset's response (which didn't work for me) led me to this answer:

You can add this command to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
command="/usr/bin/env VARIABLE=<something> $SHELL" ssh-rsa <key>
```

`export VARIABLE=<something>` was immediately exiting, and the SSH connection was closed (locking me out of the server), whereas `/usr/bin/env ... $SHELL` will run your default shell with a modified environment.

Comment: This just hangs when logging in for me.  When I remove it SSH returns to normal and I get my usual login shell.

Comment: @NickSweeting have you tried maybe replacing `$SHELL` with an actual shell? Also check that /usr/bin/env exists on the server.
However the solution is not perfect: I have noticed that it hang when I wanted to use `scp` or an inline command.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately never got it to work, ended up enabling `PermitUserEnvironment yes` and using `environment="..."` instead of `command="..."`.

Comment: This is working nicely for me.

Answer (score 4):

just one simple command :

```
ssh -t your_host_or_ip 'export some_var_name=whatever_you_want; bash'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was making a custom build of OpenSSH for a device with a cramfs in the home directory and /etc (Cram FS is read-only) so ~/.ssh/environment would not work not without rebuilding the entire FS and these were field deployed devices(Embedded Systems Hence the use of CRAMFS). You can specify in the sshd_config the location of the authroized_keys file but for some reason the environment= only work for environment variables in the ~/.ssh/authroized_keys. Editing the /etc/profile wasn't an option and I had to load ssh in a non-standard directory. In session.c after the child_set_env(..."MAIL"...) just add the enviroment variables you need(This is a hack I know...) but just incase someone needs some hardcoded envs for a session if you are compiling from source you can do this. TGI-FLOSS

Comment: Don't forget you can bind-mount /tmp copies of files over their original source in a read-only file system.

Answer (score 1):

You could try invoking a custom command, assuming you have password-less ssh login setup.  On the server, edit your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys entry that corresponds to the key from you client:

```
command="export VARIABLE=<something>" ssh-rsa <key>
```

Look at [this link](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html) in the section *Forced Command* for a little more detail.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work.  It runs the command and exits, so there's no interactive session.  Is that the normal behavior?  If so, that could be useful if all you want to do is allow a specific key to trigger a specific command, but if you want to pass info *that is used in a session* (as the question states) then it is useless for that purpose.  There IS no session.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
ssh gitvps "VAR=hello FOO=world ;" echo \$VAR \$FOO
```

you need to scape variables with spaces, semicolon and dollar signs ($) using symbol "\" and single cuotes

```
ssh gitvps "VAR='hello:sd%\ \;\ s%' FOO='34\$34=,rtrt' ;" echo \$VAR \$FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes I go like this:

```
ssh me@example.com bash << EOF
export VAR1=$VAR1
export VAR2=$VAR2
./script-or-command-on-server.sh
EOF
```

you can put `"sudo bash"` as well if needed

it's nice because you can put each variable on its own line, and either hard code the value or get it from your local environment

Comment: if you have spaces or special characters or whatever, you might have to adjust the command or choose a different method

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap `ssh` with `/bin/bash`, you can pass things 1:1 similar to how you interact locally with a script:

```
# SSH destination 'script' args..
SSH()
{
  local ARGS;
  printf -v ARGS ' %q' "$2" -- "${@:3}";
  ssh "$1" -- "/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -c -- $ARGS";
}
```

This does not pass the local environment to the remote `/bin/bash`, but passes all arguments without changing them.  (Passing the whole env usually is not what you want.)

Just use it as follows:

```
# To pass something as argument literally
SSH user@host 'cd "$1" && exec "${@:2}"' "$DIR" cmd args..

# to pass $envA and $envB to cmd with args..
SSH user@host 'envA="$1" envB="$2" exec "${@:3}"' "$envA" "$envB" cmd args..

# see what's passed and how:
SSH user@host 'printf "ARG: %q\\n" "$@"' '*' '`not dangerous`' $'\177' $'\n'
```

The latter prints

```
ARG: \*
ARG: \`not\ dangerous\`
ARG: $'\177'
ARG: $'\n'
```

- Unlike `ssh`, arguments passed to `SSH` are not re-interpreted

  - No fear for unquoted shell characters to do harm
  - No fear for sudden globbing on the other side
  - Filenames containing strange things (like end in `\n`) are correctly passed
- You must transfer environment variables yourself to the remote as args

  - generic environment passing is left as exercise for the reader
- To use some `ssh` option, you need to alter `SSH`

  - generic ssh option passing is left as exercise for the reader

But:

- This recipe needs `/bin/bash` on both sides.

You can adapt it to any other shell, of course.