# transfer information about the connection from ssh client to ssh server

Tags: ssh, sshd

suppose I have the following ssh session:

```
userA@boxA -> userB@boxB -> userC@boxC
```

now, from `boxC`, as `userC`, I would like to have the information that the ssh connection came from `userB@boxB` which in turn came from `userA@boxA`.

now I have the following ssh session along with the first ssh session:

```
userD@boxD -> userB@boxB
```

from `boxB`, as `userB`, I would like to have the information that the connection came from `userD@boxD` and that there is a second ssh session coming from `userA@boxA`.

is this information available and accessible as user? is it even available at all?

if not, is there any "easy" way to make this information available? with easy I mean without hacking and recompiling sshd, and without having to have root access on the machines.

Comment: If you have userA and userB's cooperation, see [When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?](http://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-fr/163228#163228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official way to send environment variables from client to server is through `SendEnv` and `AcceptEnv`. The problem is that you need root access on the server to configure `AcceptEnv`. Most servers are configured to accept no or only a few predetermined variables.

I found two tricks to send environment variables from client to server, both work without needing root access on the server.

## trick one:

```
ssh -t server SSH_ORIGIN=$USERNAME@$HOSTNAME bash
```

this will connect to server and then execute the command `SSH_ORIGIN=$USERNAME@$HOSTNAME bash`, with `$USERNAME` and `$HOSTNAME` already replaced on the client side. then, on the server side, you can further process the information contained in the variable `SSH_ORIGIN`.

the `-t` is needed otherwise bash will be started on the server without a tty (try it, you will see).

a slight modification will allow to pass the information transitively down a longer ssh chain.

```
ssh -t server SSH_ORIGIN=$USERNAME@$HOSTNAME:$SSH_ORIGIN bash
```

### discussion:

- bash is started as an interactive non-login shell (`.profile` is not read).
- bash is run twice (`.bashrc` is read twice). once by sshd and once by the user command.
- it will always start bash, ignoring your default shell on the server.

## trick two:

first you must generate a ssh key and transfer that to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. then prepend the line with `command="$SHELL"`. see the sshd manpage for more information on this.

connect to ssh server using the command:

```
ssh -t server SSH_ORIGIN=$USERNAME@$HOSTNAME
```

this will connect to the server but this time the variable assignment is not executed. instead, the string is stored in the environment variable `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`. then the command provided in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is executed. once you are in the shell you can process the information contained in `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.

as above, you can make this transitive:

```
ssh -t server SSH_ORIGIN=$USERNAME@$HOSTNAME:$SSH_ORIGIN
```

### discussion:

- it will start the default shell on the server.
- it will always start the default shell on the server. any command you give to the ssh command will be ignored and stored in `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`. if you want to execute a command over ssh you can use a different ssh key or have your shell init file to detect and execute `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.

Comment: Many servers are configured to let `LC_*` variables through (these are normally used by locales, but you can subvert them). For example, `LC_FOO=bar ssh localhost 'echo $LC_FOO'` displays `bar` on my machine under the default setup (on Debian squeeze).

Comment: @Gilles Yes, if the server accepts `LC_*` then you can use that to sneak in a variable. I have encountered some really paranoid sysadmins whose servers do not accept even the standard `LC_*` variables, they just didn't accept any variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

The command `who` tells you who else is logged in now on the same machine and where they logged in from. The command `last` gives the same information for past sessions. Depending on machine configuration and login methods, the information may not always be complete, up-to-date or available to non-root users.

In your A@A->B@B->C@C scenario, it is impossible from machine C to know that B@B was logged into B via an ssh session from A. In the 1980s, when everybody trusted everybody, you could have tried `finger` or `ident`, but these days machine B is unlikely to be even running a finger or ident daemon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could force environment variable on hostB to write address of hostA. 
Then on hostC use AcceptEnv to get environment from hostB, voila :)

read sshd_config a bit, parts regarding environment stuff.

Comment: that would only work if B cooperates fully. There is no way C can check whether the value sent by B is accurate or fabricated.

Comment: AcceptEnv has the potential to be used to relay the information i want. sadly only root can set AcceptEnv and default is to accept no environment variables. i do not have root access to the most machines i ssh to.

Answer (score 0):

From Box C, without access to Box B, you would not be able to tell that the user had come from Box A. In fact, you may not be able to tell how the user got to Box C. It simply depends on how the administrator has set things up.

Same answer for the "suppose further" question. It depends on the permissions that the system administrator has given you and the programs he or she has installed.

Relevant commands that would help you if you had permissions (but you probably don't):

```
finger - http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/finger/

last - http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/last/
```