# How to determine if the client on an ssh connection is using screen

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I have an odd predicament. I want to detect on the remote end of an ssh
connection if the client is running the terminal inside a screen
session. I want to set my prompt based on this. So far I have tried
using `remotehost:~/.ssh/env`[1] and the `SendEnv` option in my
`localhost:~/.ssh/config` to send my `$STY` variable[2]; but both have
failed.

So I was wondering if there is any other way to achieve this?

Footnotes:

[1] This doesn't work since it doesn't evaluate anything, I can't set
    things up dynamically.

[2] This requires `AcceptEnv` be allowed on the remote end. This is not
    possible because I'm not the admin on the remotehost and even if I
    were, the `man sshd_config` advises against it.

Comment: On my system, screen sets the `$TERM` variable, and it is reflected on the remote host `$TERM` variable.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/174494/transfer-information-about-the-connection-from-ssh-client-to-ssh-server

Comment: @artistoex Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm set term to xterm

Comment: @lesmana That seems to answer my question adequately. I should have searched more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [ "${TERM}" == "screen" ]
then
    # Set prompt to something special for screen.
fi
```

Here is the relevant quote from the [screen manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen):

```
   term term

   In  each  window's  environment  screen opens, the $TERM variable is set to "screen" by default.  But when no description for "screen" is installed in the
   local termcap or terminfo data base, you set $TERM to - say - "vt100". This won't do much harm, as screen is VT100/ANSI compatible.  The use of the "term"
   command is discouraged for non-default purpose.  That is, one may want to specify special $TERM settings (e.g. vt100) for the next "screen rlogin otherma-
   chine" command. Use the command "screen -T vt100 rlogin othermachine" rather than setting and resetting the default.
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, I already set TERM to something else to resolve other issues (e.g. scrolling). I did get my answer in the thread referred to by artistoex.