# How to set SSH time to the Windows machine time

Tags: windows, ssh, time

I am a beginner in these things, so please go light on me!

At the suggestion of a community member, I ask this question here, in addition to StackOverflow.

I have a device which I connect to my PC (Windows machine) via USB and after <s>rooting SSH</s> SSH-ing into it as an user, I can change the date and time using the following command:

**date -s '2019-08-21 05:12:44'**

I can obviously do that by hand, but I would like to learn how can I bring the Windows machine time into that command line.

Thank you very much!

Edit: It is a custom built hardware which runs Linux and it has 3 real-time clocks. I connect it to the PC via USB cable, but it has builtin Bluetooth and WiFi capabilities.

Second edit: I wanted to say that I SSH into the device as the "root" user.

Using Python with the Paramiko library I managed to bring the Windows machine time into the Linux one with the following code:

```
import datetime
import paramiko
import time

#create SSH client

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

#automatically add the host key

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

#connect to the Linux device

client.connect('address', username='username', password='password')

#delay subsequent commands by 10s to be sure the connection is established

time.sleep(10)

#execute command

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(str(str("date -s '" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))[:-7] + "'")) #bring in the local Windows machine time
stdin.close()

print(stdout.read(),)
```

Strangely enough, if I don't use the following line of code, it doesn't work:

```
stdin.close()
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/702751/950948 construct time string in env variable on local host and use it in remote command but time not updated in your variable magically - you need to update variable on host each time before executing command on remote. In other words you cant get actual local time from remote via ssh and shell.

Comment: (1) "after rooting SSH into it" -- So there's network between the Windows PC and the device, right? (2) What OS runs on the device? Is there a real-time clock? Is the device Raspberry Pi? (3) To "bring the Windows machine time into that command line" would be a poor solution. A better solution may be to run an NTP server on Windows and an NTP client on the device automatically, but we need more information from you to guide you. Please [edit] the question and tell us more. Responding to my questions is a good start. Do not respond in comments, add information to the question body.